# Understanding the first part in the proof of Proposition 9 on pg.151 in Royden and Fitzpatrick 4th edition.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

The proposition and the first part of its proof are given below:

> [image]

**My questions are:**

1- why in case $p=\infty,$ we are sure that there is a subset $E_{0}$ of $E$ of measure zero for which $g$ is bounded on $E \setminus E_{0}$?

2- How is the simple approximation lemma leads to that there is a sequence of simple functions on $E \setminus E_{0}$ that converges uniformly on $E \setminus E_{0}$ to $g$ and why this leads to that it converges with respect to the $L^{\infty}(E)$ norm.

Here is the picture of the Simple Approximation Lemma.

> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is because of the fact that the essential supremum of $g$ is finite (as it is in $L^\infty(E)$). Then on $E\setminus E_0$ the Simple Approximation Lemma applies. We find such $\phi_n$ and $\psi_n$ for $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{n}$ (if you like we can extend them to $E$ by setting them $0$ or $+\infty$ or whatever you like on $E_0$ to have them to be simple functions on $E$, which are still essentially bounded), and quite clearly on $E\setminus E_0$, $\|\phi_n - f\|_\infty \le \frac{1}{n}$ (everything is finite here), so this holds as essential sup on $E$ too. Basically we can ignore what happens on $E_0$.

Comment: Sorry if this a trivial question, why is $g$ a measurable function?

Comment: @Secretly by definition of being in $L^\infty(E)$.

Comment: but I looked at the definition on pg.136 in the middle and I can not see anything saying that $g$ must be measurable ..... I am sorry if this also a trivial question?

Comment: @Secretly I don’t have that particular book, but just a book by Royden alone.

Comment: which edition do you have?

Comment: I can send you the book via email if you like ..... I do not know how to upload a book here.

Comment: @Secretly Real Analysis, 3rd edition. On page 118 there (start of chapter 6, *The Classical Banach Spaces*) he starts with "a measurable function defined on $[0,1]$ is said to belong to $L^p=L^p[0,1]$ if..." and later "it is convenient to denote by $L^\infty$ the space of all bounded measurable functions on $[0,1]$ (or rather all measurable functions which are bounded except possibly on a subset of measure zero)." etc.

Comment: Why can we set $\phi_{n}$ and $\psi_{n}$ equal to $\infty$ on $E_{0}$ are not they simple functions?

Comment: @Secretly he then defines the general case in Chapter 11, par. 7 (after a whole lot of general theory on metric and Banach spaces) for $L^p(\mu)$: "as in Chapter 6 we define $L^\infty(\mu)$ to be the space of bounded measurable functions." and later "we set $\|f\|_\infty = \operatorname{ess sup}|f|$" etc.

Comment: @Secretly A simple function with one extra value on $E_0$ is also simple.

Comment: ohhh because by definition it takes a finite number of values and this does not mean that those values are finite ..... am I correct?

Comment: @Secretly not for general extended real functions indeed. But you can also set it to $0$ if you prefer.

Comment: what do you mean by the first sentence in your previous comment?

Comment: I do not understand from where you get $$\|\phi_n - f\|_\infty \le \frac{1}{n}$$ and why everthing is finite here?